# connect SQL Server in django rather than default database

Tags: django, settings, django-settings

How to connect SQL Server in django rather than default database? What do I have to write in "settings.py" file?

Answer (score 1):

You actually can install package for mssql:

```
pip install mssql-django
```

Then change your settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user@myserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

And btw you can turn off pyodbc's connection pooling by adding this in your settings:

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION_POOLING = False
```